# How to disable form autocomplete in semantic-ui-react?

Tags: forms, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

How can I disable autocompleting form with credentials in semantic-ui-react? Tried this but it does not work

```
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
<Form autoComplete="off">
....
</Form>
```

Comment: Funny. I wish I could make it work instead of prevent it. 
For me it just doesn't work, even with proper "autocomplete" attributes on the input elements in the DOM...

Answer (score 3):

```
<Form autoComplete="off">
</Form>
```

WOrks for me... Shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can put `autoComplete` on `Form`.
Instead try it on either `Form.Group` or on each `Input`.

Comment: Indeed it works, but you need to mind the case with a capital `C` like you wrote above, even so it shows `autocomplete` when rendered as HTML attribute...

Comment: It does not work, Safari still try to fill Input out in the Form.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. It works on mine when I tested it on my application. So it's not a problem with semantic-ui-react.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for my case, the name of the Dropdown field is "state" so Chrome address autofill ignores the autocomplete attribute.
After some struggle, I found that role="presentation" does the trick.
So I get the input ref from the dropdown by ref.ref.firstChild, and setAttribute('role', 'presentation'). It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

`<Form autoComplete="off">` will render to HTML `<form autocomplete="off">` ([link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs/autocomplete)) and it will then disable the autocompletion for all the form fields, **except for passwords** because of [link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields.), where we can also read :

> If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent autofilling of password fields, you can use autocomplete="new-password".

Which leads to the second part of the answer : how to set the `autocomplete` attribute for individual fields ? either *off* or *new-password* or any of [link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs/autocomplete) (*given-name*, *email*, *country* …).

The components don't have a specific prop for it ([link3](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form)), but that can be resolved by passing a content template to the component :

```
<Form.Input type="password" name="mypassword" required>
    <input autoComplete="new-password" />
</Form.Input>
```

The component will then merge both the template attributes and its props to render :

```html
<div class="ui input">
    <input autocomplete="new-password" name="mypassword" required="" type="password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions do not work, it is also possible to disable the autocomplete function for individual input fields.

```
<Form.Input autoComplete='new-password' type="password" />
```

Will render:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui input">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
</div>
```

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3743